# VSCode Mac, extra characters in debug console

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

When doing a `std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;` in vscode for Mac it always prints `@"Start\r\n"` to the debug console.

Is there a way to get rid of the `@"\r\n"` characters so that it would only print `Start`?

Best, Hu

Answer (score 0):

You probably currently using `llbd` , try using *externalConsole* instead, by adding `"externalConsole": true` to `launch.json`, which will send the output to a separate terminal window.